# bluemix libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found

Tags: java, servlets, glibc, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

My apps are web app projects (java liberty pack).

I want to run executables with java process builder in servlets but I am getting errors. That executables depends to GLIBC.

How can I solve them?

First project:

> libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found

Second Project:

> /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found

Comment: Are these programs you have built locally and are deploying within the application deploy artifacts?

Comment: Yes , I'm using centos 7 and build locally programs and deploying web applications with eclipse bluemix tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Foundry supports "stacks" which define the operating system runtime your application will be deployed onto.

```
[10:04:11 ~]$ cf stacks
Getting stacks in org james.thomas@uk.ibm.com / space dev as james.thomas@uk.ibm.com...
OK

name         description
lucid64      Ubuntu 10.04
seDEA        private
cflinuxfs2   Ubuntu 14.04.2 trusty
```

Currently, IBM Bluemix is deploying applications onto the older Ubuntu 10.04 stack by default. This environment contains GLIBC 2.11.

**You can specify which stack to deploy your application onto using the "-s" command line flag or setting this in the manifest.**

Choosing *cflinuxfs2* will use a more recent version of Ubuntu with an updated version of the glibc libraries.

This should hopefully work.

Comment: Sir, you're super ! You saved my days. Thank you a lot. It's work.